# Android - Map duplicates after alertdialog

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application in Android Studio with Firebase where I am using the map to show different things. The first time the user enters the MapsActivity a alertdialog pops up with some information. My prpoblem is that when the "OK" button is pressed the application automatically duplicates the activity and the "new" activity is ran. When i press the back button I can go back to the "original" activity again. I don't understand why it does that. Any ideas why?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;

DatabaseReference database;
DatabaseReference userRef;

FirebaseUser user;
String userId;
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userId = user.getUid();
    username = user.getDisplayName();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    userRef = database.child("User").child(userId);

    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild("dialog")){
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("hi");
                dialog.setMessage("Some text");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        userRef.child("dialog").setValue(true);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: use on viewCreated and display dialog inside that.!

Comment: I am not using a fragment, so I cannot use onviewCreated

Comment: mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); run your  addValueEventListener() after this method.!

Comment: I just tried, it still duplicates

Comment: What you actually want to do.?

Comment: I want the activity not to duplicate

Comment: use finish() on Ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157076/discussion-between-atif-abbasi-and-jdoe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when you use **addValueEventListener** in firebase

if this code is called twice ..  the function in it will execute twice !

so if you want this Information Just once and dont have to track the node

you can use  **addListenerForSingleValueEvent**

In your code when you click OK you modify the Node you Track So

your activity Duplicate

Comment: I have changed my code so I use addListenerForSingleValueEvent, but this does not help. In the Android Monitor I can see that it creates the activity again when I click "OK"

Comment: But you are right. When I remove the firebase code and only run the alertdialog code, it does not duplicate. So it must be something with the firebase code

Comment: can you write code that open this activity 
and you can accept my answer if it solve your problem

Comment: What do you mean with "code that open this activity"?

Comment: There are no parent activity

Comment: your application Start with this activity?

Comment: I do have a activity that starts this activity, but I don't see how that is effecting the MapsActivity

Comment: Elsunhoty - I just realized that your are right. I fixed the problem by using addListenerForSingleValueEvent in my parent activity. Thanks for the help, it just took me a minute to understand

Answer (score 1):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("hi");
                dialog.setMessage("Some text");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Can't use the "this" keyword

Comment: use MapsActivity.this  instead of this.

Comment: Okay, tried it. It does not work, still does the same